# Schedule operation bash

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

I need to compute N operation (same operation) each hour.

For the moment I have my operations but I can't understand execute it N time per hour:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 N=10; 
 # my operation
 sleep 3600/${N}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to know how to do arithmetic in bash or do you want to schedule a command (e.g. with cron)?

Comment: As @honk hints, you should do this using `cron`

Comment: no no, not using crontab, I think is not for my purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you have it written now, it will only perform "my operation" once, after which it will sleep for 6 minutes, and then exit. What you need is a loop construct around those two lines. `bash` supports several different loop constructs, but probably the simplest for this case would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10
((delay=3600/N))
while true
do
  # do something
  sleep ${delay}
done
```

Of course, there's no provision for terminating the loop in this case, so you'll have to exit with `^C` or `kill` or something. If you only wanted it to run a certain number of times, you could use a `for` loop instead, or you could have it check for the [non-]existence of a certain file each iteration and exit the loop when you create or remove that file. The most appropriate approach depends on the bigger picture of what you are really trying to do.